# Trying to POST data to secure FORM

Tags: html, security, post, authentication, forms

This is the form:
https://is.sce.ac.il/nidp/idff/sso?id=11&sid=0&option=credential&sid=0
the code I USED is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="document.forms['asd'].submit();">
<form name="asd" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="https://is.sce.ac.il/nidp/idff/sso?sid=1" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="credential" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Ecom_User_ID" value="XXX" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Ecom_Password" value="XXX" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But I get to a page call "Novell Access Manager 3.1"
Is there a way to do simple login?

Answer (score 0):

The form action is set to this link: https://is.sce.ac.il/nidp/idff/sso?sid=1

Is that the desired page you wish to handle the login function? Please post the code from that page or change the link in your script.

Comment: the main resault is to have HTML file on my desktop that will do an auto-login (JS submiting FORM) to that system (I have UNAME and PASS)..  
BUT, I can't get it to work.  
this is the source link:  
http://portal.sce.ac.il/  
It refferer me to:   
https://is.sce.ac.il/nidp/idff/sso?id=11&sid=1&option=credential&sid=1     
this is the login form I want be auto submit on my desktop